# Select the cell in which the panes are frozen in each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA to select a cell in different sheets:

```
Sub Positioning()
Sheet1.Select
Range("B2").Select
Sheet2.Select
Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

As you can see right now I manually select **Cell B2** in each sheet.
All this works fine.

---

Now I **froze panes** at different breaking points in both sheets:

```
Sheet 1: Freezing Panes at Cell D5
Sheet 2: Freezing Panes at Cell C3
```

How do I have to change my VBA code so it **automatically detects** in which cell the panes are frozen and then selects exactly that cell?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's impossible to detect where exactly the panes are frozen. It is however possible to choose, where the panes should be frozen via VBA. Perhaps you should reconsider your question with this information in mind?

Comment: Perhaps to be more clear - try to think of your question this way - Instead of asking *"How do I detect where panes are frozen?"* try to ask yourself the question *"How do I freeze panes for specific criteria?"* Question like that is far more likely to get answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following

```
Sub SelectTopofFreezePane()
    With ActiveWindow
        If .SplitRow > 0 Or .SplitColumn > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(.SplitRow + 1, .SplitColumn + 1).Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Update after comments**

To do this on each sheet loop through the sheets in the workbook and activate each one. You can stop this being shown to the user by using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

```
Sub SelectTopofFreezePane()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveWindow
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            ws.Activate
            If .SplitRow > 0 Or .SplitColumn > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(.SplitRow + 1, .SplitColumn + 1).Select
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks. Your code works already very good on the active sheet. However, is it also possbile to do the code globally so it runs automatically through each sheet in the file. I tried something like this Sheet1.Cells(.Split Row ...., Sheet2.Cells(.SplitRow .... but I could not make it work :-(

Comment: it will only work with the `ActiveWindow` and `ActiveSheet`. You could loop through the workbook and `Activate` each sheet but that's your only option as far as I know